# draw dynamic tree

Tags: c#, visual-studio, drawing, draw, c#-datatable

How can I draw a dynamic family tree
So that whenever you add or remove a family member, the tree will paint itself

I tried drawing on bitmap but I couldn't draw it
Family data in a local database

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here... you are mixing up 3 separate things. Do you want to actually draw something on a bitmap, create a TreeView control and populate it, or are you trying to do something with a database? Your question makes no sense to me without code or further explanation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Creating interactive Family Tree is not an easy task, literally it could take years to do it. I would suggest you to use some existing Family tree component like [BALKAN FamilyTreeJS](https://code.balkan.app/family-tree-js/first-look#JS). It is very easy to configure and has Edit/Add/Delete/Share etc functionalities build-in. Also you can use it in WinForms or WPF with WebView 2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use and call [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com) as freely available external tool.

PlantUML reads a text input and generates a graphical output in various formats.

**Example input:**

```
@startwbs
* Marjory & John I
** Elena & Tom
*** John II
*** Thekla
** Marion & Mustafa
@endwbs
```

**Resulting output:**

[image]

To use this from within a C# application, you could call PlantUML as external process and import the resulting bitmap graphics file into your C# picture control.

Comment: While this (interesting) link __may__ solve his problem, it certainly doesn't answer his question(s).